# is there a way to save a temporary file as a permanent raster layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, table, hdf

I am trying to build a raster table for a temporary layer i created from an image difference on ArcGIS image analysis. Is there a way to save the temporary layer from this image analysis as a permanent .img file/hdf file or something along those lines ?

Answer (score 1):

right click on your layer and chose "make permanent" (with geostat analyst) or "export data"